# Pandas dataframe merge and element-wide multiplication

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['al', 'ben', 'cary'], 'bin':[1.0, 1.0, 3.0], 'score':[40, 75, 15]})

    bin     name    score
0   1   al  40
1   1   ben     75
2   3   cary    15
```

and a dataframe like

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'bin':[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0], 'x':[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
                    'y':[0, 0, 1, 1, 0], 'z':[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]})

    bin     x   y   z
0   1   1   0   0
1   2   1   0   0
2   3   0   1   0
3   4   0   1   1
4   5   0   0   0
```

what I want to do is extend df1 with the columns ‘x’, ‘y’, and ‘z’, and fill with score only where the bin matches and the the respective ‘x’, ‘y’, ‘z’ value is 1, not 0.

I’ve gotten as far as 
    df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['bin'])

```
    bin     name    score   x   y   z
0   1   al  40  1   0   0
1   1   ben     75  1   0   0
2   3   cary    15  0   1   0
```

but I don't see an elegant way to get the score values into the correct 'x', 'y', etc columns (my real-life problem has over a hundred such columns so df3['x'] = df3['score'] * df3['x'] might be rather slow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just get a list of the columns you want to multiply the scores by and then use the `apply` function:

```
cols = [each for each in df2.columns if each not in ('name', 'bin')]
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['bin'])
df3[cols] = df3.apply(lambda x: x['score'] * x[cols], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be much faster than iterating, but is an idea.

Import numpy, define the columns covered in the operation

```
import numpy as np
columns = ['x','y','z']
score_col = 'score'
```

Contruct a numpy array of the score column, reshaped to match the number of columns in the operation.

```
score_matrix = np.repeat(df3[score_col].values, len(columns))
score_matrix = score_matrix.reshape(len(df3), len(columns))
```

Multiply by the the columns and assign back to the dataframe.

```
df3[columns] = score_matrix * df3[columns]
```